Некорректный тип значения
У меня есть объект следующего вида:
file: { 
    createdAt: "2024-08-11T08:14:23.794Z",
    filename: "4kz0phxsmg.mp4",
    filesize: 2860606,
    id: "66b872df4996ceba0199fbbc",
    mimeType: "video/mp4",
    name: "Russian (ru)",
    updatedAt: "2024-08-11T08:14:23.794Z",
    url: "/media/4kz0phxsmg.mp4"}

Я передаю значение в функцию из объекта следующим способом:
LogoView(file.filename)

функция
const LogoView = (Doc: any) => {
    console.log(typeof Doc,Doc)
;}

Но вместо того, чтобы увидеть в логе значение '4kz0phxsmg.mp4', получаю объект с этим значением: {Doc: '4kz0phxsmg.mp4'}.
Кто сможет объяснить, почему так происходит?
Дополнения:
полный код элемента
  import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as DownloadIcon } from "shared/assets/svg/bootstrap-icons-1.11.2/download.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Excel } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/excel-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Powerpoint } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/ppt-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Word } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/word-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as PDF } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/pdf-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as FileUnknown } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/unknown-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Xml } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/xml-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Zip } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/zip-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Video_File } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/video-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Music_File } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS//audio-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Txt } from "shared/assets/svg/SVG-DOCS-ICONS/txt-document-svgrepo-com.svg";
import "./Files.scss";
import { Button } from "shared/ui/button";
type Props = {
  files: any;
};
const word: string[] = ["doc", "docx", "docm", "dotx", "dotm", "rtf"];
const excel: string[] = [
  "xls",
  "xlt",
  "xlm",
  "xlsx",
  "xlsm",
  "xltx",
  "xltm",
  "xlsb",
  "xla",
  "xlam",
  "xll",
  "xlw",
];
const powerpoint: string[] = [
  "ppt",
  "ppt",
  "pot",
  "pps",
  "ppa",
  "ppam",
  "pptx ",
  "pptm",
  "potx",
  "potm",
  "ppam",
  "ppsx",
  "ppsm",
  "sldx",
  "sldm",
  "pa",
];
const zip: string[] = ["zip", "rar", "7z", "gzip"];
const Fvideo: string[] = ["mp4", "ogv", "webm"];
const Fmusic: string[] = ["mp3", "ogg", "wav"];
export const Files = ({ files }: Props) => {
   
  const LogoView = (Doc: any) => {
    console.log(typeof Doc,Doc);
    Doc = Doc.Doc;
    const FileType: string = Doc.split(".").pop();

    console.log(typeof Doc,Doc);
    if (word.includes(FileType)) {
      return <Word />;
    } else if (excel.includes(FileType)) {
      return <Excel />;
    } else if (powerpoint.includes(FileType)) {
      return <Powerpoint />;
    } else if (zip.includes(FileType)) {
      return <Zip />;
    } else if (Fvideo.includes(FileType)) {
      return <Music_File />;
    } else if (Fmusic.includes(FileType)) {
      return <Video_File />;
    } else if (FileType === "pdf") {
      return <PDF />;
    } else if (FileType === "xml") {
      return <Xml />;
    } else if (FileType === "txt") {
      return <Txt />;
    } else {
      return <FileUnknown />;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="block__files">
      {files.map((item: any) => {
        return (
          <div className="file__wrap">
            <div className="file__icon">
              <LogoView Doc={item.file.filename} />
            </div>
            <div className="name-file">{item.file.name}{item.file.filename}</div>
            <a href={item.file.url} download>
              <Button Icon={DownloadIcon}>Скачать</Button>
            </a>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

получаемый объект
files: {
    [file:{
createdAt:  "2024-08-11T08:14:23.794Z"
filename: "4kz0phxsmg.mp4"
filesize: 2860606
id: "66b872df4996ceba0199fbbc"
mimeType: "video/mp4"
name: "Russian (ru)"
updatedAt: "2024-08-11T08:14:23.794Z"
url: "/media/4kz0phxsmg.mp4"
}, 
    file:{ 
    createdAt: "2024-08-11T08:14:39.339Z"
    filename: "nq8wc1jctsi.jpg"
    filesize: 105882
id: "66b872ef4996ceba0199fbc3"
mimeType: "image/jpeg"
name: "there"
updatedAt: "2024-08-11T08:14:39.339Z"
url: "/media/nq8wc1jctsi.jpg"}]}


Получается string 4kz0phxsmg.mp4. Проблему не удается воспроизвести.

Открываем документацию реакта и видим, что в компоненты всегда передаётся один аргумент — объект props, и уже внутри этого объекта лежит прописанные в JSX атрибуты, в том числе и атрибут Doc, то есть typescript тут вообще ни при чём
